# xctool test -only TestTarget:TestClass runs tests disabled in the scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xctool

We have a Scheme (say `PhoneRegression`) with a couple of test targets in it (e.g. `PhoneSearchTests`, `PhoneCheckoutTests`) each with their own classes. 
In one of our Jenkins jobs we only want to run the `PhoneCheckoutFormValidationTests` in `PhoneCheckoutTests`. Our configuration is the following:

```
xctool -scheme PhoneRegression \
-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=latest" \
-reporter junit:build/junit.xml -reporter plain \
test -only "PhoneCheckoutTests:PhoneCheckoutFormValidationTests" -freshInstall
```

We noticed this works. But it does run test methods that are *disabled* in the `PhoneRegression` scheme.

How can we tell `xctool` to adhere the scheme when specifying our test targets in `-only`?

Cross posted as an issue on the [xctool github page](https://github.com/facebook/xctool/issues/657)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** the github issue has since been solved